# Query to fusion table always returns full table

Tags: google-fusion-tables

This is my  fusion table :https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1Y_0g6bDr3I9HaWhi-1IuB_d8ADGIs7n-6jvczD_n
 [image]

I have tried this query :

```
layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
  query: {
    select: '*',
    from: '1Y_0g6bDr3I9HaWhi-1IuB_d8ADGIs7n-6jvczD_n',
    where: 'Text = 33'
  }
});
```

and

```
 layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
  query: {
    select: '*',
    from: '1Y_0g6bDr3I9HaWhi-1IuB_d8ADGIs7n-6jvczD_n',
    where: "Text = '"+input+"'"
  }
});
```

In the second query, the `input` is the variable obtained from user input.
Two query return the whole table. Could you suggest to me what is wrong in this query.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just found out the problem.

```
 layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
  query: {
    select: '*',
    from: '1Y_0g6bDr3I9HaWhi-1IuB_d8ADGIs7n-6jvczD_n',
    where: 'Text = 33'
  }
});
```

In this query, the I should use `select: 'Location'` instead of select: '*', so if you have the same problem (`where` does not work), please make sure you add the **location** column, and no need to specify other columns as the query will automatically return all columns in your table